# in javascript im getting an error when converting the following string to json object, anybody help me find whats wrong with this string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

What should I do in order to fix this string to be a vali1d javascript JSON object?

```
      txt = '{"Categories" : 
              [{"label":"petifores","id":"1"},
               {"label":"wedding cake","id":"2"},
               {"label":"shapes of cakes","id":"3"},
               {"label":"printable photos","id":"4","children":
               [{"label":"series","id":"7"},
                {"label":"kids","id":"8"},
                {"label":"animals","id":"9"},           
                {"label":"sport","id":"10"},
                {"label":"various pictures","id":"11"},
                {"label":"Cars","id":"12"},
                {"label":"girls","id":"13"},
                {"label":"artists","id":"14"}]
                {"label":"special events","id":"5"},
                {"label":"graduations","id":"6"}]}';
```

Comment: paste your json object at jsonlint.com and you will be able to fix it.

Comment: You can copypaste your json here: http://jsonlint.com/. I've done and it says there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing a closing `}`. I found it using http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "Categories": [
        {
            "label": "petifores",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "label": "wedding cake",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "label": "shapes of cakes",
            "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "label": "printable photos",
            "id": "4",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "series",
                    "id": "7"
                },
                {
                    "label": "kids",
                    "id": "8"
                },
                {
                    "label": "animals",
                    "id": "9"
                },
                {
                    "label": "sport",
                    "id": "10"
                },
                {
                    "label": "various pictures",
                    "id": "11"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Cars",
                    "id": "12"
                },
                {
                    "label": "girls",
                    "id": "13"
                },
                {
                    "label": "artists",
                    "id": "14"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "special events",
            "id": "5"
        },
        {
            "label": "graduations",
            "id": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is valid.

PS. I removed the single-quotes. So if you want to use that as a string, add it again

Answer (score 0):

You are missing these `},` after the `children`.

Change it to (see `},` in bold):

txt= '{"Categories" : [{"label":"petifores","id":"1"},{"label":"wedding cake","id":"2"},{"label":"shapes of cakes","id":"3"},{"label":"printable photos","id":"4","children":[{"label":"series","id":"7"},{"label":"kids","id":"8"},{"label":"animals","id":"9"},{"label":"sport","id":"10"},{"label":"various pictures","id":"11"},{"label":"Cars","id":"12"},{"label":"girls","id":"13"},{"label":"artists","id":"14"}]**},**{"label":"special events","id":"5"},{"label":"graduations","id":"6"}]}';

Check a working jsFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/fp1q69y9/

Answer (score 0):

I have found your error, look at `{"label":"artists","id":"14"}]{"label"`  and replace by `{"label":"artists","id":"14"}]},{"label"`.

You can use this site for help: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

yes you've missed } of id 4, after closing it's children.

```
 "id":"14"}]  },  {"label":"special events","id":"5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing } after id:14

```
{"Categories" : [{"label":"petifores","id":"1"},{"label":"wedding cake","id":"2"},{"label":"shapes of cakes","id":"3"},{"label":"printable photos","id":"4","children":[{"label":"series","id":"7"},{"label":"kids","id":"8"},{"label":"animals","id":"9"},{"label":"sport","id":"10"},{"label":"various pictures","id":"11"},{"label":"Cars","id":"12"},{"label":"girls","id":"13"},{"label":"artists","id":"14"}]},{"label":"special events","id":"5"},{"label":"graduations","id":"6"}]}
```

string now correct